# Does the Aberrant Mind Sorcerer Subclass' Warping Implosion Ability Affect the User?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer

For the Aberrant Mind sorcerer origin, it's lv 18 ability, Warping Implosion, reads as follows:

> You can unleash your aberrant power as a space-warping anomaly. As an action, you can teleport to an unoccupied space you can see within 120 feet of you. Immediately after you disappear, each creature within 30 feet of the space you left must make a Strength saving throw. On a failed save, a creature takes 3d10 force damage and is pulled straight toward the space you left, ending in an unoccupied space as close to your former space as possible. On a successful save, the creature takes half as much damage and isn’t pulled.

So, if you teleport to within 30 feet of where you were before, do you need to make a saving throw and potentially take damage and get sucked closer? I can see this playing out one of two ways

1. Since the saving throws are made right after you disappear, you haven't reappeared yet and are thus unaffected
2. Since it is teleportation, the moment you disappear you also reappear in your new location and thus would be affected

Answer (score 9):

### Yes

If you are a “creature within 30 feet of the space you left” then you meet the criteria for being affected. Teleportation is instant so you arrive at the same time as you leave which is temporally *before* “immediately after you disappear” happens.

Comment: You just picked one of the possible scenarios described by OJ and paraphrased it, without saying *why* this is the correct one. I don't see how this is a helpful answer.

Comment: In particular, this answer ducks the important-looking language, "Immediately _after you disappear_..." and "the space you left..."

Comment: It is also worth considering the XGtE rules for ordering simultaneous events, since immediately after you disappear and when you reappear are simultaneous events (or at the very least could reasonably be interpreted to be simultaneous).

Comment: @NautArch the optional rule isn't for the subclass, it's to allow for the possibility of it being used in the game. Since the feature is being used on their turn (action and all that), in a game that is using the optional rule, the sorcerer's player would control the timing of when the damage was triggered

Comment: I'm not sure what more Dale M could cite; there's no rule about how teleporting works that would make this interpretation _incorrect_. Nothing states you are 'missing' for any length of time while teleporting, so it must be assumed that you continually exist at either the source or destination, in which case you're in range.

Answer (score 5):

[Note: the question's title asks generally whether Warping Implosion affects the user, but the question itself adds the supposition that the user teleported within the area of the damage effect. I'll try to address both.]

### Warping Implosion (Generally) Does Not Affect the User, Because the User Has (Probably) Already Left the Affected Area by the Time the Damage Effect Triggers...

Critical to **Warping Implosion** is the fact that the force damage only triggers "*after* you disappear" and only affects an area around "the space you *left* . . . ." Logically, if you have left that space when the force damage triggers, you are no longer there and would not be affected by it.

### ...*Unless* the User Chooses to Teleport to a Space Within 30 Feet, in Which Case the User is (Probably) Affected...

As has oft been observed of 5e, there are no hidden rules. In particular, there is no hidden rule that a teleporting creature ceases to exist or to occupy any physical location, for any length of time, between disappearing and reappearing.

Anecdotally, my own experience at many game tables has been 100% consistent: teleportation means you cease to exist in one space and immediately begin to exist in another.

As far as I can tell, there is nothing in any official 5e resource published to date to suggest otherwise. A review of numerous teleport-type effects througout the 5e range confirms that none of them suggest any kind of pause or hesitation between disappearing and reappearing. In particular, I reviewed:

- the spells *teleport*, *far step*, *misty step*, *thunder step*, *scatter*, and *word of recall*;
- the Conjuration wizard's **Benign Transposition** and Way of Shadow monk's **Shadow Step** abilities;
- the **Teleport** abilities of a couple dozen monsters, from blink dogs to the demon lord Kostchtchie; and
- the teleport-type abilities granted by the *astral shard* and *atlas of endless horizons*.

Some of these abilities use descriptive words like "instantly" to modify the verb "teleport." Some don't. But *none* of them suggest there is any delay between disappearing and reappearing.

Of special note is the phase spider's **Ethereal Jaunt** ability:

> As a bonus action, the spider can magically shift from the Material Plane to the Ethereal Plane, or vice versa.

The phase spider's lore entry clarifies that this ability resembles, but is not actually, teleportation: the spider

> *seems* to appear out of nowhere and quickly vanishes after attacking. Its movement on the Ethereal Plane before coming back to the Material Plane makes it *seem* like it can teleport.

(Emphasis mine.) I read this to mean that it is the seeming instantaneousness of the spider's travel that gives the impression that the spider is teleporting -- but the travel isn't actually instantaneous, and the spider isn't actually teleporting.

Given the above, the best conclusion one can draw is that an Aberrant Mind sorcerer using Warping Implosion to teleport ceases to exist in one space and immediately begins to exist in another. Warping Implosion's damage effect also happens "immediately after you disappear," so if the space you choose to teleport to is within 30 feet of the one you left, you would be a "creature within 30 feet of the space you left" and would be affected by the damage.

### ...*Except* If You're Using the Optional "Simultaneous Effects" Rule from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, in Which Case the User Gets to *Choose* Whether to Be Affected.

Viewed as I propose above, Warping Implosion only cares about two time-states: (1) *before* you disappear, which is used to determine the space you will have left when you do disappear; and (2) *immediately after* you disappear, which is when *both* your appearance in a new space and the force damage effect happen simultaneously.

*XGtE* offers the following entirely optional rule for "rare cases" when "effects can happen at the same time":

> If two or more things happen at the same time on a character or monster’s turn, the person at the game table — whether player or DM — who controls that creature decides the order in which those things happen.

If your table uses this rule, then the sorcerer's player gets to decide whether the damage effect or the reappearance in a new space happens first. By choosing to have the damage effect happen first, the player can choose to teleport to a space within 30 feet of the space s/he left yet still avoid the damage.

Comment: sorry for the harsh words, but this answer is as useless as the other one. I'm not sure if we have any rules for this, but in my opinion, answers should answer the question as a whole, not just the title. Answering just the title while ignoring the body does not make for a good answer, and the part where you address the body is, like the other answer, just a reiteration of one of the scenarios mentioned by OP, without any justification why *that* scenario is correct and not the other one.

Comment: You could've been nicer about it -- a problem that seems sadly endemic to RPG.SE -- but your point is taken nevertheless. I really thought the logic here was straightforward. Regardless, I've attempted to show my work.

Comment: While there may not be a time gap between disappearing and reappearing, there is one teleportation ability that suggests those are two separate events, and it's **Warping Implosion**. Why else would it say "immediately after you *disappear*", and not "immediately after you teleport", or just "immediately after"? Unfortunately, you can't reliably choose an unoccupied space if everything else moves between your disappearing and reappearing, so I still think this is the best answer we can get without a Crawford tweet.